# Slicer (with multiple selections) On Multiple Values In One Column Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I have a table named "Combined" for example is

| PersNumber | ProductName |
| --- | --- |
| P-1 | A |
| P-2 | B |
| P-3 | A, B |
| P-4 | B, A |
| P-5 | C, A |

I've created a separate table with all distinct values for the slicer by doing this

```
= let
    Source = Combined,
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"ProductName", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "ProductName"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"ProductName", type text}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"ProductName", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Trimmed Text")
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

This new table is just named "Table". I'm now stuck on how to make the slicer be able to choose A AND B showing all PersNumbers that contain A AND B (in the example it would be P-3 and P-4).

Please let me know if you need any more information or if you need me to clarify anything. I'm open to doing it a different way as well.

I've tried creating a measure to apply to the filter of the visual

```
check_ = 
VAR _selected = SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[ProductName])
RETURN
IF (
    CONTAINSSTRING ( SELECTEDVALUE (Combined[ProductName]), _selected )
        || ISBLANK(_selected),
    1,
    0
)
```

But this only allows me to select one option and if I select more than one option it just goes to the next one and selects all PersNumbers that contain that second choice (NOT BOTH like I was hoping).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've ever gotten a slicer to do AND. One option (which is a bit messy) is to create two disconnected slicers and then use INTERSECT() which does what you want (but it has to be on a single column).

Sorry, I'm going to cheat. I already have a file that has a table Diagnoses(PatientID, SymptomName, Date, Severity), so I'm going to use that.

```
PatientsWithDiabetes = CALCULATETABLE('Patient',FILTER('Diagnoses',[SymptomName]="Diabetes"))

PatientsWithHeartFailure = CALCULATETABLE('Patient',FILTER('Diagnoses',[SymptomName]="Heart Failure"))

patients with D and HF =
INTERSECT(PatientsWithHeartFailure, PatientsWithDiabetes)
```

(basically, INTERSECT(table A, table B) returns all members that exist in *both* tables.)

Comment: I like the Intersect idea but I wouldn't be able to manually create each combination because I have 106 ProductNames. Is there a way to do this dynamically with the slicer choice?

Answer (score 0):

How many items are you trying to test for intersection at a time? Doing two is just

`INTERSECT('TableA'[Column1],'TableB'[Column2])`,

and if you wanted to compare a third set, you'd do

```
INTERSECT(INTERSECT('TableA'[Column1],'TableB'[Column2]),
'TableC'[Column4])
```

Are you saying you have an indeterminate number of sets to compare at once? I'm not sure how you would do that in DAX, because as far as I know, it can't do recursion (the way you can with common table expressions in T-SQL for example to answer a question like "Show me all the prerequisites of a given course where you have a table of (CourseID, Prerequisite CourseID), and a table of Courses (CourseID, Title)